# Force capitalization of first word of textfield ios

Tags: ios

Can we forced first latter of first word in textfield to be capitalized always without giving any automatic option?

I know there is option in xib attributes for textfield but they again give option as a popup suggestion. I dont want that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just manipulate the string after the user has entered it?...

Simply change the first letter of the string to be uppercase, to do this:

```
NSString *yourString = yourTextField.text;
yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) 
             withString:[[yourString substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
```

This will change, for example, `here is your string` to `Here is your string`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting 'Capitalization' to 'Sentences' in the Attributes Inspector for the TextField?

...or do it programatically:

```
[textField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences];
```

Comment: It still gives you option as popup to change

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to prevent capitalization by removing the button from the keyboard?

Comment: No i dont remove anything. I just simply want to force user to add first latter of word as capital. Thats it. no matter he enters it as caps or non caps